# Property and Collection observer in Aurelia not raising propertyChanged event

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a model object representing "players" in DB. in it's implementation there is an array of players, which i would like to bind to from different VM's in my app. for example:

```
import {Players} from './models/players';
import {inject, BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Players,BindingEngine)
export class App {

  constructor(playersProvider,bindingEngine) {
    this._playersProvider = playersProvider;
    this._bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
    this._subscription = this._bindingEngine.propertyObserver(this,this._playersCount)
      .subscribe(this.objectValueChanged);
  }

  async activate() {
    await this._playersProvider.initialize();
    this._playersCount = this._playersProvider.players.length;
  }

  objectValueChanged(newVal,oldVal) {
    console.log("new : " + newVal + ", old val : " + oldVal);
  }

  deactivate() {
    this._subscription.dispose();
  }
}
```

unfortunately, when a change is made to the players array (from other parts in the app) the change is not reflected in _playersCount property. e.g. - UI label bound to this property is not refreshed, and objectValueChanged never gets called.

U have the same issue in a different VM with a collectionObserver on the same array.

any help?

Comment: the syntax is `this._bindingEngine.propertyObserver(this, '_playersCount')`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to declare _playersCount in the constructor before subscribing to it?

Also the synthax does not seem correct, it should be according to [this article](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/10/observing-objects-and-arrays-in-aurelia/):

```
import {BindingEngine, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(BindingEngine)
class MyClass {
  constructor(bindingEngine) {
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
    this.observeMe = 'myvalue'; // the property is first initialized in the constructor

    let subscription = this.bindingEngine
      .propertyObserver(this, 'observeMe') // <= you wrote this._bindingEngine.propertyObserver(this,this.observeMe)
      .subscribe(this.objectValueChanged);

    // Dispose of observer when you are done via: subscription.dispose();
  }

  objectValueChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(`observeMe value changed from: ${oldValue} to:${newValue}`);
  }
}
```

The async keyword might affect the behaviour.
If it still does not work, you can use an event aggregator to broadcast the change.